# Is there a if functionality in Karate framework?

Tags: karate, gherkin

Here is the sample code

```
"xNotification": [
      {
        "code": "1234",
        "text": "Invalid Data"
        "yNotification": [
          {
            "code": "345",
            "text": "Invalid Data"
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
 }
```

yNotification array only exits sometimes in the response, when it exists I need to capture the code value and put it in a variable. I don't want assert just when it exists I need to put it in a variable. I am newbie to any testing frameworks. I appreciate any help with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this part of the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

Example:

```
* def expected = zone == 'zone1' ? { foo: '#string' } : { bar: '#number' }
* match response == expected
```

EDIT: This is the complete solution to your question:

```
* def response =
"""
{ "xNotification": [
      {
        "code": "1234",
        "text": "Invalid Data",
        "yNotification": [
          {
            "code": "345",
            "text": "Invalid Data"
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
"""
* def code = karate.get('$.xNotification[0].yNotification[0].code')
* print code
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for quick response, but that that's not what I am looking for. Let me rephrase my question is there a way to find "yNotification" key exists or not in the above response Or yNotification array exists in the response or not? Above JSON is my response. Thank you

Comment: @GlenChaba see my edit. next time, please have the courtesy to put well-formed JSON. please read the docs. `karate.get()` will return `null` if the path does not exist and you can even supply a default value in the same syntax / one line

Comment: Peter, sorry for the malformed JSON, next time I'll be more careful. Thank you for the solution.